# If multi-core CPUs share the MMU, can multiple processes run in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, cpu-architecture, multicore, mmu

If multi-core CPUs have a dedicated MMU for each core, multiple processes can run in parallel.I want to know what will happen if multi-core CPUs share the MMU.

I guess,if multi-core CPUs share the MMU, multiple processes can run in parallel. MMU looks at multiple different page tables at different times. Is this true? Can you give a detailed explanation?

Comment: Each core has its translation-lookaside buffer (TLB), which the OS manages (on mmaps/munmaps and context switches), and physical memory accesses are then synchronized via cache-coherency protocols.

Comment: "The MMU" isn't a separate thing in modern CPUs; the TLBs are integrated with load/store execution units (and the code-fetch stage for the iTLB), with page-walk hardware as a fall back.  (Except on ISAs like classic MIPS with software TLB miss handling).  [Is the TLB shared between multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34437371) (no).  So IDK how to answer your question because such a design seems so obviously bad and inconvenient that IDK why anyone would build something that way.  Maybe really old systems where integrating an MMU was too much, but they really wanted SMP?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you. If this design exists, multiple cores can compute at the same time, but cann't use the MMU at the same time. Is it multiple processes in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

> If multi-core CPUs share the MMU, can multiple processes run in parallel?

If CPUs share the same MMU (same page tables, etc); then all CPUs must have the same virtual memory, and with nothing else this would make it impossible to have multiple processes (with different virtual address spaces) running in parallel.

However; it'd be easy to have something (e.g. segmentation) to split the whole virtual address space into "zones". For example; if process1 is only able to access the first 1 GiB of the virtual address space, process2 is only able to access the second 1 GiB, and processN is only able to access then Nth GiB; then multiple processes can share the same virtual address space without conflicts or security problems. If the size of the zones are constant; this is functionally equivalent to having a separate MMU for each zone.

> I want to know what will happen if multi-core CPUs share the MMU.

What would happen is either:

- nobody would buy it because it's a dodgy joke (because it can't run multiple processes in parallel), so it'll end up being a few chips in a museum somewhere that everyone laughs at; or
- the first version will behave the same as "separate MMU per CPU", and then the second version will be "separate MMU per CPU" to improve performance.

In other words, "companies competing for profit" tends to ruin the viability of products that suck.

Comment: Worth mentioning explicitly that running multiple threads of the *same* process on different cores can be useful for performance, and you could imagine an OS that context-switches all cores at once.  But yes, you'd only build it that way if transistor budgets were too small to integrate things but you really wanted both SMP and virtual memory.  I wonder if anything like that ever existed in the 1960s or 70s.

Comment: @Brendan Thank you. If the virtual address is not divided into zones, which is not functionally equivalent to having a separate MMU for each zones, then each core accesses the MMU at different times and computes at the same time. Is it multiple processes in parallel?

Comment: @FrasietteBuffay: For performance an MMU is mostly TLB entries (with a slow way to fetch a TLB entry when there's a TLB miss). TLB entries can't be time multiplexed (switched between processes rapidly to emulate processes in parallel) because they need to persist for a duration to be beneficial. To fix that you'd have to tag the TLB entries with an "address space ID" so that many TLB entries from many processes can be kept at the same time; but as soon as you do that you don't need time multiplexing; and you can say the "address space ID" is part of the virtual address used to select a zone.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning ASIDs in this answer. They are much more natural than the zones thing (which would still require some tagging but would be much more cumbersome) and would allow having a single global (possibly separately) MMU.

Comment: @Brendan Thank you.TLB entries can't be switched between processes rapidly to emulate processes in parallel, but an "address space ID" can select a zone,an "address space ID" tag a TLB entry so that many TLB entries from many processes can be kept at the same time.So many processes can access the MMU in parallel.